# "with" in Is that alright with everybody?

Tags: prepositions

Is that alright with everybody?

What does the word "with" mean here?
Can I use "for" or "to" here?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably better not to look for a synonym for _with_ that works here. Prepositional distribution is a nightmare. Accept that 'Is that alright with everybody?' means 'Does everybody think that that is all right?' (Alright is nonstandard.)

Comment: _with_ has many meanings in the dictionary. I went through them carefully but couldn't find one that works in this context. Could you give me another sentence with a similar usage of the word "with"? Tks

Comment: Are you comfortable ***with*** the idiomatic use of prepositions?

Comment: @ScotM, but that puts the sentient being[s] at the other end of the relationship, no longer object of preposition *with.*

Comment: I'm comfortable with friends who challenge my theses, @BrianDonovan ;-)

Comment: @ScotM I think he means "I'm all right with it" is different from "It is all right with me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*With* is fine, a good choice even, for the dative sort of relation that seems to be intended. Merriam-Webster [s.v. *with*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with) offers two definitions that may be applied to this usage:

> 5 a:  in the judgment or estimation of
>
> 2 c: in respect to:  so far as concerns

*For* could also work here. Not so *to* unless you were to recast the question as something along the lines of “Does that sound good to everybody?” or “Is that acceptable to everybody?”

No one should fault you for choosing *with.* But some (by no means all) will fault you for using *alright* as opposed to *all right:* see usage note in [Merriam-Webster entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alright).

Comment: Thanks for the note on alright vs all right.
I know with works here. but I want to know which meaning of with is used here? and I want to know whether for and to work here

Comment: I have re-edited above answer in response.

Comment: *For* would be idiomatic too, but it would subtly transform the focus from the passive consent in *all right with* to more of a utilitarian consent in *all right for*, which implies *that* is a means towards everyone's end.